# Find out module versions through database dump

Tags: 6, database, backups

I've got a dump from my Drupal database that I've created with [Backup and Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate).

I want to find out which versions of the modules *ctools* and *Panels* have been in use.

Where do I have to look? What do I have to search for?

Comment: Sounds like you have a running site, so why don't you simply look at the modules list using the Drupal UI? Care to explain what you're after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Import the dump file into mysql database. Create a new database in your localhost and import the db using your backup file
- Browse **System** table.
- Run below query

  SELECT info 
  FROM  `system` 
  WHERE  `filename` LIKE  '%ctools.module%'
  ORDER BY  `system`.`name` ASC 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
- You will see version information in info column. Search for "Version". Above information is serialized.
- For Example, As you see below "Ctools" module is 6.x-1.11 version. You can do same for panels module by changing query.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from database dump, with the "Views System" module you can get details (although it seems a bit unstable).